logit model (odds ratio) - marginal effects
I'm currently working on a dataset - "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv"
I'm trying to run a logistic regression between one column and the other variables.
logistic regression
admit=alpha+beta1gre+beta2gpa+beta3*rank
I wonder how to calculate the change in odds ratio(admit) when gpa score from 3 to 4 after fixed the rank and gre.
R code(how to solve this problem)
